# I want to order keys values of a list of objects using python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, object

**I need some help to change this array and make the objects inside, having the same order of keys**

```
"lines":[
     {
        "name":"n1",
        "salary_group_id":"Badr Office",
        "Basic Salary":5000.0,
        "**Unpaid Leave**":0.0,
        **"Other Allowances** ":0.0,
        "**Housing Allowance**":500.0,
        "Company Contribution For Employee":605.0,
        "Contribution For Employee":-495.0,
        "Gross":5500.0,
        "Loan":0.0,
        "Net Salary":5005.0
     },
     {
        "name":"n2",
        "salary_group_id":"Badr Office",
        "Basic Salary":6500.0,
        "**Housing Allowance**":500.0,
        "**Unpaid Leave**":0.0,
        "**Other Allowances** ":0.0,
        "Company Contribution For Employee":770.0,
        "Contribution For Employee":-630.0,
        "Gross":7000.0,
        "Loan":0.0,
        "Net Salary":6370.0
     }
  ]
```

**i want this to become:**

```
"lines":[
         {
            "name":"n1",
            "salary_group_id":"Badr Office",
            "Basic Salary":5000.0,
            "Unpaid Leave":0.0,
            "Other Allowances ":0.0,
            "Housing Allowance":500.0,
            "Company Contribution For Employee":605.0,
            "Contribution For Employee":-495.0,
            "Gross":5500.0,
            "Loan":0.0,
            "Net Salary":5005.0
         },
         {
            "name":"n2",
            "salary_group_id":"Badr Office",
            "Basic Salary":6500.0,
            "Unpaid Leave":0.0,
            "Other Allowances":0.0,
            "Housing Allowance":500.0,
            "Company Contribution For Employee":770.0,
            "Contribution For Employee":-630.0,
            "Gross":7000.0,
            "Loan":0.0,
            "Net Salary":6370.0
         }
      ]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own, yet? That's pretty straight forward and quite easy to achieve

Comment: yes i did but i didn't find a solution
can you do and share a simple solution ?

Answer (score 0):

this answer only works with python 3.6+ where dictionary keys order is preserved (and the problem asked only has a solution with the same python versions)

Extract the list of keys with given order. Then rebuild the sub-dictionaries following this order

```
sdata = [{k:d[k] for k in model} for d in data["lines"]]
```

The dictionaries rebuilt in the list comprehension follow the order of the `model` list of keys on any python version >= 3.6

full code:

```
data = {"lines":[
     {
        "name":"n1",
        "salary_group_id":"Badr Office",
        "Basic Salary":5000.0,
        "Unpaid Leave":0.0,
        "Other Allowances":0.0,
        "Housing Allowance":500.0,
        "Company Contribution For Employee":605.0,
        "Contribution For Employee":-495.0,
        "Gross":5500.0,
        "Loan":0.0,
        "Net Salary":5005.0
     },
     {
        "name":"n2",
        "salary_group_id":"Badr Office",
        "Basic Salary":6500.0,
        "Housing Allowance":500.0,
        "Unpaid Leave":0.0,
        "Other Allowances":0.0,
        "Company Contribution For Employee":770.0,
        "Contribution For Employee":-630.0,
        "Gross":7000.0,
        "Loan":0.0,
        "Net Salary":6370.0
     }
  ]}

model = list({
            "name":"n1",
            "salary_group_id":"Badr Office",
            "Basic Salary":5000.0,
            "Unpaid Leave":0.0,
            "Other Allowances":0.0,
            "Housing Allowance":500.0,
            "Company Contribution For Employee":605.0,
            "Contribution For Employee":-495.0,
            "Gross":5500.0,
            "Loan":0.0,
            "Net Salary":5005.0
         })


sdata = [{k:d[k] for k in model} for d in data["lines"]]

>>> sdata
[{'name': 'n1', 'salary_group_id': 'Badr Office', 'Basic Salary': 5000.0, 'Unpaid Leave': 0.0, 'Other Allowances': 0.0, 'Housing Allowance': 500.0, 'Company Contribution For Employee': 605.0, 'Contribution For Employee': -495.0, 'Gross': 5500.0, 'Loan': 0.0, 'Net Salary': 5005.0},
{'name': 'n2', 'salary_group_id': 'Badr Office', 'Basic Salary': 6500.0, 'Unpaid Leave': 0.0, 'Other Allowances': 0.0, 'Housing Allowance': 500.0, 'Company Contribution For Employee': 770.0, 'Contribution For Employee': -630.0, 'Gross': 7000.0, 'Loan': 0.0, 'Net Salary': 6370.0}]
```

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: not with my data, no. There's a "lines" key in the data. the `["lines"]` access can be removed in that case `sdata = [{k:d[k] for k in model} for d in data]`